# Using Batch argument in a bash terminal

Tags: git, bash, batch-file, git-bash

I'm trying to do the following in a batch script:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL

set BASHPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\"
set PATH=%BASHPATH%;%PATH%
set COMMIT=%1
echo COMMIT: %COMMIT%
%BASHPATH%\bash -l -c "echo COMMIT: $COMMIT \ && git checkout -f $COMMIT \ && git submodule update -f \ && git clean -fdx \ && git submodule foreach git clean -fdx \ && call $SCRIPT_PATH\name_all.sh \ && call $SCRIPT_PATH\name_all_log.sh \ && cd FCW \ && cd ObjectDetectionTest \ && exit; bash";
set CYGWINPATH="C:\cygwin64\bin"
set PATH=%CYGWINPATH%;%PATH%

ENDLOCAL
```

But when I run the script, `$COMMIT` translates to nothing! So, What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What was the input and output?

Comment: I see where you set `%COMMIT%`, but where do you set `$COMMIT`? (They're totally different variables!)

Comment: @SomethingDark - No, they're not different variables - at least not in the way you mean.  When a bash shell inherits its environment from a Windows shell, `%FOO%` is inherited as `$FOO` due to the different conventions used by the different shells

Comment: @MohamedAmeen - I don't see why this wouldn't work, and the same pattern worked fine in a mocked-up test I just ran.  You are remembering to pass the commit value as the 1st parameter when you run the script, right (since you read it from `%1`)?

Comment: @Mark Adelsberger Thanks for putting me right, even if you downvoted my answer. I repect that. I did test my answer, but inattentively edited it to better fit as an answer. And broke it.

Comment: @OP For debugging purposes: I assume that the batch echos %COMMIT% as expected and only bash echos $COMMIT as empty. True?

Comment: @OP I've moved set `PATH=%BASHPATH%;%PATH%` to be after `set COMMIT=%1` and the `echo COMMIT: %COMMIT%` before bash works well. But the echo inside bash gives nothing and the script gives this `error: pathspec ' ' did not match any file(s) known to git.`

Comment: Well, I'm mostly at a loss as I simply can't reproduce this.  One idea I suppose - could there be something in your bash login scripts interfering with what you're trying to do?  (You're passing `-l` to bash, which makes it work like a login shell; does this work if you *don't* pass `-l`?)

Answer (score 0):

From a bat script, I managed to make this work with:

```
set COMMIT=%1
echo COMMIT: %COMMIT%
bash -l -c "COMMIT=%COMMIT% bash -l -c 'echo \${COMMIT}'"
```

Meaning:

- letting the bat script resolve `%COMMIT%` in the bash command.
- calling a bash within a bash, after setting `COMMIT` in the first `bash -c`
- escaping the `$`